# Создание одной сессии на всё время существования сервиса

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

Корректно ли в aiohttp создать сессию на всё время жизни сервиса? Какую роль в aiohttp играют сессии? Хранят ли они пул коннектов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, так можно и нужно делать именно потому что сессии хранят пул коннектов.

> aiohttp.ClientSession should be created once for the lifetime of the
>   server in order to benefit from connection pooling.
>
> Sessions save cookies internally. If you don’t need cookie processing,
>   use aiohttp.DummyCookieJar. If you need separate cookies for different
>   http calls but process them in logical chains, use a single
>   aiohttp.TCPConnector with separate client sessions and
>   own_connector=False.

[proof](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-manage-a-clientsession-within-a-web-server)

Comment: Хорошо бы побольше подробностей в ответ добавить)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik какие подробности Вы желаете?

Comment: Которые вы добавили, а то ответы-ссылки не приветствуются)